# How to add style in order email template in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3

Once I do order from Magento site then I can see in email template "Payment Method" and it is not style well. So I wan to add some CSS style. Can you please let me know where I can add it?

Answer (score 0):

To add style to an email template you must override the standard email template. Go in the admin section, to `Marketing -> Communications -> Email templates`.

Here, click on `ADD NEW TEMPLATE` and in the prompted window, either load a pre-existing email template or create a new one inserting the html in **Template Content**. The CSS, on the contrary, must be inserted in the **Template Styles** section.

Eventually, go in `Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Email` and choose the new template in the section you need.

Comment: @NileshPatel did it work?